# Postgres 9.6.1 Full Text Search dictionaries for most spoken languages

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-9.6

Using Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.5, I am trying to run full text search operations, such as `to_tsvector`, `to_tsquery`, etc and have a need for [dictionaries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SIMPLE-DICTIONARY) in about 80+ languages.

Postgres seems to only come with 16 language configurations, with an additional two I am testing for Chinese (`jiebacfg` and `testzhcg` aka `ZHParse`). I'm looking for documentation or a repository of other languages beyond these.

```
mydatabase=# \dF

               List of text search configurations
   Schema   |    Name    |              Description              
------------+------------+---------------------------------------
 pg_catalog | danish     | configuration for danish language
 pg_catalog | dutch      | configuration for dutch language
 pg_catalog | english    | configuration for english language
 pg_catalog | finnish    | configuration for finnish language
 pg_catalog | french     | configuration for french language
 pg_catalog | german     | configuration for german language
 pg_catalog | hungarian  | configuration for hungarian language
 pg_catalog | italian    | configuration for italian language
 pg_catalog | norwegian  | configuration for norwegian language
 pg_catalog | portuguese | configuration for portuguese language
 pg_catalog | romanian   | configuration for romanian language
 pg_catalog | russian    | configuration for russian language
 pg_catalog | simple     | simple configuration
 pg_catalog | spanish    | configuration for spanish language
 pg_catalog | swedish    | configuration for swedish language
 pg_catalog | turkish    | configuration for turkish language
 public     | jiebacfg   | configuration for jieba
 public     | testzhcfg  | 
(18 rows)
```

I've installed [Ispell Dictionary](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-ISPELL-DICTIONARY) in attempt to get more dictionaries, and then tried installing a few of the dictionaries [from the list](https://lasr.cs.ucla.edu/geoff/ispell-dictionaries.html), but many are quite arduous to install, don't have the [necessary `.dict` files](http://ispell-pl.sourceforge.net/), are for [Windows only](https://lasr.cs.ucla.edu/geoff/ispell-dictionaries.html#Hebrew-dicts), or are [simply unavailable](http://7kosova.com/kde-shqip/ispell/ispell.html).

I'm looking for perhaps updated ways to install language dictionaries for Postgres 9.6.1.

---

Will need support for: (the one's with lang. next to it means it's already pre-installed with PG 9.6.1)

```
French  french
Español spanish
Afrikaans   
Albanian    
العربية 
Armenian    
Azerbaijani 
Basque  
Belarusian  
Bengali 
Bosnian 
Bulgarian   
Catalan 
Cebuano 
Chichewa    
中文（简体)  
中文（繁體)  
Croatian    
Czech   
Danish  danish
Dutch   dutch
Esperanto   
Estonian    
Filipino    
Finnish finnish
Galician    
Georgian    
Deutsch german
Greek   
Gujarati    
Haitian Creole  
Hausa   
Hebrew  
Hindi   
Hmong   
Hungarian   hungarian
Icelandic   
Igbo    
Indonesian  
Irish   
Italian italian
Japanese    
Javanese    
Kannada 
Kazakh  
Khmer   
Korean  
Lao 
Latin   
Latvian 
Lithuanian  
Macedonian  
Malagasy    
Malay   
Malayalam   
Maltese 
Maori   
Marathi 
Mongolian   
Myanmar 
Nepali  
Norwegian   norwegian
Persian 
Polish  
Portuguese  portuguese
Punjabi 
Romanian    romanian
Russian russian
Serbian 
Sesotho 
Sinhala 
Slovak  
Slovenian   
Somali  
Sudanese    
Swahili 
Swedish swedish
Tajik   
Tamil   
Telugu  
Thai    
Turkish turkish
Ukrainian   
Urdu    
Uzbek   
Vietnamese  
Welsh   
Yiddish 
Yoruba  
Zulu    
English english
```

Comment: Experience (a long time ago) let me to look for the dictionaries used by OpenOffice.org or the ISpell dictionnaries listed at https://lasr.cs.ucla.edu/geoff/ispell-dictionaries.html. The configurations themselves, I am afraid you'll have to make them 'by hand'.